# How change the size of button and text in Kendo ui grids?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How can I change the size of buttons and text (or style) in Kendo ui grids?
I want to use them for a responsive web page (mobile and desktop).

Change the text size of rows is easy:

```
columns: [
   {
      field: "Title",
      width: 100,
      attributes: {
            "class": "myClass",
            style: "font-size:20px;"
      }
   } 
]
```

But I don't know how change the size of the title of columns  and  buttons

Comment: I'm trying to do this as well. In Bootstrap it's dead simple to add a class attribute like **"btn-sm"** or **"btn-xs"**, but apparently in Kendo it's not so simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid) section you can see how you can change the messages the Grid uses or the text for the buttons. use ctrl+f and search for 'message' and 'text'.

Customizing the buttons style is not a good idea (imo). However you can just use CSS classes with "stronger" selectors.

Comment: and where can I find the button selectors?

Comment: They are not documented anywhere. You need to use the dev tools of your browser to see what they are and see what exactly is the structure of the Grid